# Renting bikes in Copenhagen

Tags: bicycles, copenhagen

I've a trip planned to Copenhagen in late November, is it fairly common for people to rent a bike and explore the city? I'm specifically asking as I'm not sure about people riding a bike in November as it tends to get cold early in that part of the world.

Comment: Is there anything particular you are concerned about? Are you worried about cold temperatures or perhaps rather icy or snowy roads? If the problem is the low temperatures, you can simply put on more clothes. If the problem is slippery roads, it rather depends on the bicycle. There are also bicycle tyres designed to ride on snow or ice, but I am not sure if you can find them on any rental bikes.

Comment: I am quite sure you won't find spiked tyres on rental bikes, in particular not in Copenhagen in late November, as you almost certainly won't need them.  Copenhagen is not far north and is not cold.

Comment: @gerrit But since we've already had snow in northern Germany this fall, I wouldn't bet on a snow free November in Copenhagen, which is north of here.

Comment: @Sumyrda Depending on the odds, I'm quite willing to bet that a specific date in November will be snow-free in Copenhagen, at a small chance of losing...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It does not get cold in Copenhagen in November.  It has a maritime climate and [the average daytime temperature in November is +7.1°C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copenhagen#Climate) (24-hour average +5.1°C).  The **record** low for November is -7°C, which is still no problem for cycling with a hat and gloves.  You do not need any special bicycle or special outdoor gear apart from normal layers for a mild winter.

It should certainly be possible to rent a bicycle in November.  Some outlets may be closed as it's a low season, so you should contact rental agencies in advance.

Comment: "-7°C, which is still no problem for cycling with a hat and gloves." Getting out of breath in temperatures that low isn't at all fun if you're not used to it. But, as you say, it's extremely unlikely to be *that* cold so this is kinda moot.

Comment: …and glasses! Riding without glasses is pain.

Comment: @DavidRicherby True, but +2°C with rain and strong winds is quite possible.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: You've got a point, but from the OP's description ("rent a bike and explore the city") I doubt they're going to do any riding that would get them out of breath anyway. Copenhagen is also flat as a pancake, so there aren't even any steep hills to struggle with.

Answer (score 12):

I live in Copenhagen and use my bike to go to work all year like many other locals. There are plenty of bike rentals for tourists as this is a popular way to explore the city.

You will find that the scenic city centre and waterfront a best travelled by foot or by bike as car traffic is restricted.

Its is a very good city for cycling with high priority to bicycle and foot traffic and bike lanes everywhere. If there is snow in the winter the bike lanes in the main roads are cleaned quite quickly by the municipality.

November weather is normally nice, but some rain and wind is likely. Snow is unlikely. Bringing  gloves is probably a good idea. That time of year I would also recommend bringing a light poncho or raincoat just in case.

Please be note that you can bring your bicycle on the S-trains and Metro so you can combine the door-to-door flexibility and ubiquitous free parking possibilities of the bicycle with public transport for longer distances.

It is free to bring a bike on the S-train: in the Metro you need an extra ticket and there are certain restrictions during rush hour traffic.

Comment: Appreciate the tips and info.

Answer (score 10):

We currently have mild weather in Copenhagen and it should stay that way for the coming month too, although you may see snow and sleet eventually. That should not be a big problem, given the correct clothes, as stated by others.

As for bikes, check this out: http://bycyklen.dk/en

Answer (score 6):

As far as I remember people cycle all year long. Maybe when it snows a bit less people do it due to ice.

Relating to renting, the city used to have a free public bike system. The problem sometimes is more to find a bike available.

Answer (score 2):

While there are many good answers, I think there is a big point being missed here: **the great unpredictability of Danish weather**. Contrary to what [another answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/57766/36512) claims, the temperature can go way lower than -7. For instance, the Danish extreme for November is [just below -21 degrees Celcius](https://translate.google.dk/translate?hl=da&sl=da&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dmi.dk%2Fvejr%2Farkiver%2Fnormaler-og-ekstremer%2Fvejrekstremer-dk%2F) (and there's not much difference across the relatively small country). Also, autumn/early winter is the season for [storms in Denmark](https://translate.google.dk/translate?hl=da&sl=da&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fda.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FNavngivne_storme_i_Danmark), which (on its own, cold or warm) may make it very impleasant and/or dangerous to go outside.

My point: you should be able to rent a bike and explore the city, but beware that in November the Danish weather can vary a lot, so check the forecast before you go, and maybe have a plan B ready.

Comment: Just because a freak minimum of -21°C has been measured once in the last 150 years doesn't mean temperatures that cold (or even below freezing in daytime) are by any means common for November.

Comment: "Contrary to what another answer claims, the temperature can go way lower than -7." I cannot find any source contradicting that answer's claim that the lowest recorded November temperature in Copenhagen is -7C (except for some sources claiming 18F, which rounds to -8C). Denmark is small but it's not tiny and the -21C record you quote was set in Tarm, which is 250km (150mi) from Copenhagen. I'm pretty sure you're more likely to be struck by lightning in November in Copenhagen than encounter -21C.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I did not state that -21°C is common, did I?

Comment: Just 7 years ago: [-9.2°C in Roskilde 2008](http://vejret.tv2.dk/artikel/id-18403929.html). First snow in Denmark [typically falls in November](http://vejret.tv2.dk/artikel/id-34411083%3Avinterens-frste-/id-34411083%3Avinterens-f). If anyone knows of any source claiming that Copenhagen be _significantly_ warmer than the country average, I'm all ears.

Comment: Sure, you're not claiming that -21C is common. My point (and I think also Henning's) is that it's so astonishingly rare that it's not even worth mentioning. We're not claiming that Copenhagen is "significantly warmer than the country average" -- we're claiming that Copenhagen (and all of Denmark!) is, on average, significantly warmer than the coldest temperatures ever recorded. Any internet search for Copenhagen weather statistics returns essentially the same results so I'm mystified as to why you're asking us for sources that Copenhagen is significantly warmer than -21C or -9C in November.

Comment: I agree to the point that an extreme isn't representative data, but as -7°C was presented as the record low by the accepted answer, I think that is to say that _this_ is astonishingly rare for November, which, in my opinion, deserved a counterstatement. So I believe you missed my point of mentioning it in the first place.

Comment: As for your mystification, I can see how you're curious when you believe I stated that the _country average_ is -9 or -21.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is quite common, there is actually a lot of tourism in relation to bike tours, walking tours and boat canal tours. For instance Nova Fairy Tales (former Copenhagen Fairy Tales) has a pretty [good bike tour in CPH](https://www.novafairytales.com/).

Regarding time of the year, I think you should be fine in November as long as you wear warm clothes. It's mostly in the period of December to February, that it can happen to snow. You'll see a lot of natives bike even in these period, so I'm sure you can still enjoy a bike tour in November.